# How to tell if an Android app is in the "stopped" state?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have an Android app that registers a `BroadcastReceiver` to handle ringer mode changes.  The receiver is registered through the manifest, not dynamically.  Some users report that occasionally the app doesn't respond to a ringer mode change, although manually launching the app and subsequently changing the ringer mode does trigger the app.  Some time later, however, the app stops responding to ringer mode changes again.

The symptom sounds suspiciously like the app is getting into the "stopped" state; but I don't have any reason to believe that users are explicitly force closing the app, and I'm not aware of any other way that an app could get into the "stopped" state.

Is there a way for a user to determine if an app on their (non-rooted) phone is in the stopped state, so I could validate/invalidate the "stopped" state theory?  I don't think it is sufficient to look at whether the "force close" button is enabled, since it would be disabled both for stopped apps as well as apps not currently running.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? Seems I have the same.

Comment: @GoltsevEugene No, still an issue for me.

Comment: I'm searching for an answer to this, too.  Some android ROMs seem to have a non-standard tasks switcher that, after killing apps, put them into the stopped state, whereas the AOSP task switcher does not do this.

Comment: Researching AOSP source, it seems that this flag is stored in the stopped member of `PackageUserState`.  Unfortunately, I can see no way to access that field from non privileged code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can query all applications on a device and see which ones are in a stopped state with this code:

```
private List<String> getStoppedPackages() {
    ArrayList<String> stoppedPackages = new ArrayList<String>();
    final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

    for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
        boolean appStopped = (packageInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_STOPPED) != 0;
        if (appStopped) {
            String description = packageInfo.packageName;
            stoppedPackages.add(description);
        }
    }
    return stoppedPackages;
}
```

I made a utility app that does this for you here:

https://github.com/davidgyoung/stopped-app-detector

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks, I had googled 'til my googler fell off and hadn't found that API.  Bonus points for making the demo app.  Now I can start to build up a reference list of Android implementations that have this behavior.

Comment: I'd be interested in sharing data about device specific behavior if you are as well.  I have found one device that disallows service restart after killing in the task switcher.  Strangely, I see that this happens despite the stopped state **not** being set for the app after killing it.  I wonder if there is a different but similar flag as well.

Comment: @davidgyoung Is there a way to get this information via `adb` ?

Comment: You might try this command:  `adb shell dumpsys package com.example.MyApp` and see if STOPPED shows up in `flags=[ ... ]`